# Entity Framework datareader already open nested entity loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have two entity lists being retrieved from the database they are using the same context and the same connection string.  They have naviagation properties and these load fine, when I get them from the context i.e `IQueryable<EntityA> A = context.EntityA.Include("V"), IQueryable<EntityB> B = context.EntityB.Include("V")`

There is a nested loop i.e.

```
foreach(EntityA a in A) {
  foreach (EntityB b in B) { 
    if (b.V.property == a.V.property) {
      // do something 
    } 
  }
}
```

When it gets to EntityB in this loop a datareader already open exception is thrown.  I understand why this is happening, because they are sharing the same connection string and conetext however I am not sure what the solution is.
Thanks

Comment: It will be better if you write more code about connection out of question body :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly what sure your data access patter is (repository pattern etc...) but I would try to iterate somewhere before the "foreach" loop and iterate through the loop from memory.  You can use a simple `ToList()` rather than looping over the `IQueryable<T>`

You can directly query into the list or wherever you're bringing your IQueryable into, just add to list at the end. Thats all I can suggest until I see more code.

Comment: I thought that once you assignment, IQueryable<EntityB> B = context.EntityB.Include("V"), took place to object B would be loaded with all the values inlcuding navigation properties.  I seems that you have to store it in a list, List<EntityB> BList = B.ToList().

Comment: IQueryable<T> is an interface that will hold the "query" until it gets enumerated in a view, a `foreach` loop, `.Any()`, `.ToList()` etc...

Comment: Using the IQueryable has its place as EF will try to combine all the "queries" in the best possible single transaction and same both expensive queries and transactions.  However, you just have to be aware of when you're actually enumerating your query.